# Using requestContinuation to make pagination in Spring-Data-CosmosDB

Tags: scala, pagination, spring-data, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using spring-data-cosmosdb 2.2.2 with azure-cosmos 3.6.0 and Scala.

I'm using CosmosTemplate to create custom DocumentQueries using sorting and pagination.

My problem is to navigate through the pages in my request using requestContinuation. Every request (POST) is returning a requestContinuation like that:

"requestContinuation": "{\"compositeToken\":\"{\\"token\\":null,\\"range\\":\\"{\\\\"min\\\\":\\\\"05C1DFFFFFFFFC\\\\",\\\\"max\\\\":\\\\"FF\\\\",\\\\"isMinInclusive\\\\":true,\\\\"isMaxInclusive\\\\":false}\\"}\",\"orderByItems\":[{\"item\":\"8b90e589-09d8-42e7-a3e2-d26cf2c38a63\",\"map\":{\"item\":\"8b90e589-09d8-42e7-a3e2-d26cf2c38a63\"}}],\"rid\":\"I9lLALNXyUNECgEAAAAACA==\",\"inclusive\":true}"

The first thing I saw is the inner "token" is always null.

I tried to copy the whole string and put it on my request as parameter but it didn't work:
POST https://baseurl/api/documents/recent?page=1&requestContinuation=...

The requestContinuation never changes and the documents returned in the page are always the same. I'm using Postman and Insomnia.

I don't find good examples to use requestContinuation.
Am I missing something? Maybe encoding the token with base64?

I don't know if the problem is just to pass the requestContinuation or if there's something wrong in my code.

In resume I'm just using paginationQuery method to execute a documentQuery with some criterias and a "pageable" object.

My Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = Array("/api"))
class DocumentController(@Autowired private val service: DocumentService) extends BaseController {

  @PostMapping(path = Array("/documents/recent"), produces = Array("application/json"))
  def findRecentDocuments(pageable: Pageable,
                          @RequestBody params: DocumentParams,
                          @RequestHeader(name="apiKey") token: String
                   ): Page[Document] = {

    service.findRecentDocuments(pageable, Option(params))
  }
```

My service:

```
class DocumentService(@Autowired private val documentRepository: DocumentRepository, @Autowired private val template: CosmosTemplate) extends BaseService {
  def findRecentDocuments(pageable: Pageable, params: Option[DocumentParams]): Page[Document] = {     

      val documentClass = classOf[Document]
      val collectionName = template.getCollectionName(documentClass)
      val defaultSort = Sort.by(Direction.ASC, "id")
      val sort = pageable.getSortOr(defaultSort)
      val criteria = QueryUtils.getCriteria(params, documentClass)

      getCriteriaInfo(criteria)
      documentRepository.findRecentDocuments(pageable, criteria, sort, documentClass, collectionName)
  }
```

My repo:

```
    class DocumentRepository(@Autowired private val template: CosmosTemplate) {

  def findRecentDocuments(pageable: Pageable, criteria: Criteria, sort: Sort, documentClass: Class[Document], collectionName: String): Page[Document] = {
    val query = new DocumentQuery(criteria)

    template.paginationQuery(query.`with`(sort).`with`(pageable), documentClass, collectionName)
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the recommended way of pagination provided in the readme section of spring-data-cosmosdb: https://github.com/microsoft/spring-data-cosmosdb/blob/master/README.md
Section: Supports Spring Data pageable and sort.

Also documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java/spring-framework/how-to-guides-spring-data-cosmosdb#pagination-and-sorting

Answer (score 0):

As I already commented in  the original issue on MS Github I found the solution changing the "Pageable" object to "CosmosPageRequest" object which uses requestContinuation.
This worked for me.

Here's the code:
https://github.com/microsoft/spring-data-cosmosdb/issues/484

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Lucas Porto, If you open to using the Java SDK, I have implemented infinite scroll with reactive Java SDK 4.0.

The "next" method in the following controller class is the server side entry point for the pagination used by the jQuery Ajax call.

[Code on GitHub](https://github.com/RaviTella/store/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ratella/store/controller/HomeController.java)